# "1 empty item" в массиве javascript

Tags: javascript

Код:

```
let a = ["1"];
let b = [];

delete a[0];

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
console.log(a.length);
console.log(b.length);
console.log(typeof a[0]);
console.log(typeof b[0]);
```

Вывод:

```
[ <1 empty item> ]
[]
1
0
undefined
undefined
```

Что такое `<1 empty item>`? И почему длинна `1`?

Comment: Вы работает с массивом, вы удалили значение из первого элемента, но сам элемент остался, чтоб удалить элемент из массива можно использовать splice `a.splice(0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Значение из ячейки было удалено, но место под другое значение осталось.

Оператор  **[delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)**  удаляет свойство объекта. Для массива - это индекс. Сам элемент не удаляется

В итоге получается разряженный массив (sparse)  (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas#trailing_commas_in_literals)

Тоже самое получается при висячих запятых

`[0, 1, null, 2, "", 3, undefined, 3,,,,,, 4,, 4,, 5,, 6,,,,];`