# создать пустое значение в массиве? для решения задачи на codewars нужно пустое значение в массиве. (null, undefined и пустая строка не подходит)

Tags: javascript, массивы

для решения задачи нужно проитерироваться по объекту и вернуть массив массивов.  Если в объекте массив пустой, то в конечный массив нужно вставить пустую ячейку. но у меня никак не выходит создать пустое значение в массиве. Пушить null, undefined, пустой массив и пустую строку не подходит.

допустим у меня есть объект и я по нему итерируюсь:

```
const obj = {
  '0': [ 8, 3 ],
  '1': [ 12, 17, 19 ],
  '2': [ 25 ],
  '3': [ 38, 35 ],
  '4': [],
  '5': [ 50 ]
};
let arr = []; 
for (let key in obj) {
    if (obj[key].length > 0) {
      arr.push(obj[key].sort((a,b)=> a-b))
    } else arr.push('')
  }
  return arr
```

P.S.:

```
expected [ [ 3, 8 ], [ 12, 17, 19 ], [ 25 ], [ 35, 38 ], '', [ 50 ] ] 
to deeply equal [ [ 3, 8 ], [ 12, 17, 19 ], [ 25 ], [ 35, 38 ], , [ 50 ] ]
```

Comment: Добавь `const x = '';` и пуш переменную **x**

Comment: не проходит. это тоже самое что пустую строку запушить. выдаёт ту же ошибку. expected [ [ 3, 8 ], [ 12, 17, 19 ], [ 25 ], [ 35, 38 ], '', [ 50 ] ] 
to deeply equal [ [ 3, 8 ], [ 12, 17, 19 ], [ 25 ], [ 35, 38 ], , [ 50 ] ]. просто не хотелось delete использовать, он вроде дырки оставляет.

Comment: Странно, у меня выдает в консоли '', а не пустоту

Comment: а должен выдавать как раз пустоту, а не ''.

Comment: Вот нашел ответ на ваш вопрос [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1286911/1-empty-item-](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1286911/1-empty-item-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5-javascript)